# is it possible to automate python to run curl command?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create an organization chart with python. The problem is extract hierarchal information which I have to go under each manager and extract that data. so for example, we have 25 senior manager and each has 50-100 regional and each of those has their own managers and staff. So the number is big and I need to automate this.

The solution I have is:
1- Curl data (web-scrape) and save as HTML for the TOP TOP manager who has 20 Senior manager.
2- read HTML file in Python using panda, extract that specific part which is a dict containing all 20 Senior managers.
3- save all senior managers in a CSV file.

It's all good by now! Now I need to run the curl command 20 times and change the command 20 times. and then again import each as HTML in Python and extract their staff..
Here where I am stuck.

Here is the code I have which is doing all 3 steps. 
step 1 - get the data from web:

```
curl -ksS --negotiate --location-trusted -u: -c ~/cookie -b ~/cookie "https://webserver/users/CEO/org -o output/ceo.html
```

the result is an HTML file with all information in it.
step2 - read html file and extract data:

```
HTMLFileToBeOpened = open("output/ceo.html", "r")
contents = HTMLFileToBeOpened.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, features="html.parser")

script = soup.find_all('script')[8].text.strip()[28:-1]
data = json.loads(script)
children_dict = {id: child['data'] for id, child in enumerate(data['children'])}

ids = {child['id'] for id, child in enumerate(data['children'])}
 df.to_csv('out.csv', header=False)
```

so the result is a CSV file including all managers working under CEO. like this:

```
{'manager1','manager2','manager3','manager4',....,'manager20'}
```

so, I need to replace the URL in my curl command in step 1 and run it again. So I have to change CEO with manager1 and run command and go through steps again..

Is there any way to do this automated?

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate shell command from Python using `os.system`

```
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    os.system(f'curl -ksS --negotiate --location-trusted -u: -c ~/cookie -b ~/cookie "{url}" -o output/{i}.html)
```

---

But a better way would be to call a subprocess.

```
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    subprocess.call(['curl', '-ksS', '--negotiate', '--location-trusted', '-u:', '-c', '~/cookie', '-b', '~/cookie', f'"{url}"', '-o', f'output/{i}.html'])

    HTMLFileToBeOpened = open(f"output/{i}.html", "r")
    contents = HTMLFileToBeOpened.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, features="html.parser")

    script = soup.find_all('script')[8].text.strip()[28:-1]
    data = json.loads(script)
    children_dict = {id: child['data'] for id, child in 
    enumerate(data['children'])}

    ids = {child['id'] for id, child in enumerate(data['children'])}
    df.to_csv('out.csv', header=False)
```

---

The best and the most pythonic way would be to use `requests`

```
for url in enumerate(urls):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")
    script = soup.find_all('script')[8].text.strip()[28:-1]
    data = json.loads(script)
    children_dict = {id: child['data'] for id, child in 
    enumerate(data['children'])}

    ids = {child['id'] for id, child in enumerate(data['children'])}
    df.to_csv('out.csv', header=False)
```

Comment: Little confused about subprocess way..so I have the first CSV file which is the 20 senior manager in it..So process should start from reading the CSV file first, Cause the URL should be generate based on the manager's name. URL needs to be changed every time based on the value in the CSV file.

Comment: the URL has /CEO/ in it in the middle, that needs to be changed to the values inside of the CSV I already have.

Comment: Yes so loop over the managers name `for manager in manager_list:` and then append the name to the url with  `f'"https://webserver/users/{manager}/org"'` instead of `f'"{url}"'`

Comment: curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Comment: for i, url in enumerate(f'"https://webserver/users/{manager}/org"'):
        print(i)
        subprocess.call(['curl', '-ksS', '--negotiate', '--location-trusted', '-u:', '-c', '~/cookie', '-b', '~/cookie', f'"https://webserver.com/users/{manager}/org"', '-o', f'output/{i}.html'])

Comment: The code you sent made no sense, why are you looping over a string?